# Filter array by criteria and by object property type

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects and I want to return only the first 2 results for each type in the object. The type is variable. I don't know exactly how many types I will have either.

For instance, I have this array:

```
var obj = [
{
    "number": 1,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 3,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 4,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 5,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 1,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 3,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 4,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 5,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 6,
    "type": "two"
}
];
```

In this example we have type: one and type: two as a simple example. The types could be anything and the number could be many.

I want this to be returned:

```
var obj = [
{
    "number": 1,
    "type": "one"
}, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "one"
} {
    "number": 1,
    "type": "two"
}, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "two" // <-- Could be several more types
}
];
```

I know I can use filter to get the results over the entire array, but I want it done for each variable type.

```
var result = obj.filter((val,i)=>i<3);
```

Comment: Question, if the `number` are out of order, do you want `1` and `2` returned, or just whatever the first two you encounter are for that `type` in the array?

Comment: Assume the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to just use an object to keep track of the number of "types" you have already retrieved from your array. Then, you can just filter with a condition (not much different in principle from the answer by [@RobinZigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond) but may be helpful to see it this way).

```js
const arr = [{ "number": 1, "type": "one" }, { "number": 2, "type": "one" }, { "number": 3, "type": "one" }, { "number": 4, "type": "one" }, { "number": 5, "type": "one" }, { "number": 1, "type": "two" }, { "number": 2, "type": "two" }, { "number": 3, "type": "two" }, { "number": 4, "type": "two" }, { "number": 5, "type": "two" }, { "number": 6, "type": "two" }];
const filtered = arr.filter((obj) => {
  // passing {} to Array.prototype.filter as thisArg to be used as counter object
  const counter = this;
  const t = obj['type'];
  if (!counter[t]) {
    counter[t] = 0;
  }
  
  if (counter[t] < 2) {
    counter[t] += 1;
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}, {});

console.log(filtered);
// [{number: 1, type: "one"}, {number: 2, type: "one"}, {number: 1, type: "two"}, {number: 2, type: "two"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is not too large, you can use this *`O(n)`* approach.

Basically, this approach groups the objects by the property `type`, then extracts the first two objects using the function `Array.prototype.slice` and finally builds the desired output as an array.

```js
let arr = [{    "number": 1,    "type": "one"}, {    "number": 2,    "type": "one"}, {    "number": 3,    "type": "one"}, {    "number": 4,    "type": "one"}, {    "number": 5,    "type": "one"}, {    "number": 1,    "type": "two"}, {    "number": 2,    "type": "two"}, {    "number": 3,    "type": "two"}, {    "number": 4,    "type": "two"}, {    "number": 5,    "type": "two"}, {    "number": 6,    "type": "two"}, {"number": 3,"type": "three"}],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {number, type}) => {
      (a[type] || (a[type] = [])).push({number, type});
      return a;
    }, {})).map(a => a.slice(0, 2)).reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be relatively simple to do this with an explicit loop - but personally I think it's nicer with the `reduce` method:

```
var result = obj.reduce((acc, nextObj) => {
    const withSameType = acc.filter(({ type}) => type === nextObj.type);
    if (withSameType.length < 2) {
      return [...acc, nextObj];
    } else {
      return acc;
    } 
} , []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to keep track of the count for each `type` and return the first two numbers for each:

```js
const obj = [{number:1,type:'one'},{number:2,type:'one'},{number:3,type:'one'},{number:4,type:'one'},{number:5,type:'one'},{number:1,type:'two'},{number:2,type:'two'},{number:3,type:'two'},{number:4,type:'two'},{number:5,type:'two'},{number:6,type:'two'}];

const map = new Map();

const result = obj.filter(({ type }) => {
  const count = map.has(type) ? map.get(type) : 0;
  map.set(type, count + 1);
  return count < 2;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group them as keys of an object and then extract the sub arrays with Object.values and flat.

```js
var obj = [{
    "number": 1,
    "type": "one"
  }, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "one"
  }, {
    "number": 3,
    "type": "one"
  }, {
    "number": 4,
    "type": "one"
  }, {
    "number": 5,
    "type": "one"
  }, {
    "number": 1,
    "type": "two"
  }, {
    "number": 2,
    "type": "two"
  }, {
    "number": 3,
    "type": "two"
  }, {
    "number": 4,
    "type": "two"
  }, {
    "number": 5,
    "type": "two"
  }, {
    "number": 6,
    "type": "two"
  },
  {
    "number": 5,
    "type": "three"
  }, {
    "number": 6,
    "type": "three"
  }
];

const grouped = obj.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  const key = Object.entries(x).find(([a, b]) => a === 'type')[1];
  if (acc[key] && acc[key].length === 2) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc[key] = acc[key] ? [...acc[key], x] : [x];
  return acc;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(grouped).flat()
console.log(result)
```